# How to generate INSERT statement that contains deleted data

Tags: sql, plsql

I'd like to create a PL/SQL script, that will delete some data from a table and it will return a string, containing a backup INSERT statement. Is there any straightforward approach, how to generate this insert statement in a generic way? I'd like something better than just concatenate the statement manually.

I dream about approach like this: SELECT * **AS_INSERT_STATEMENT** INTO my_string FROM my_table where id>10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

No, there is no syntax in SQL that generates the `insert` statements.  Instead, I would recommend that you use the `returning` clause for `delete`.  This will return the values being deleted in another table.  You can read about it [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems014.htm).

You could then generate the `insert` statement code from the values in the returning table.

However, I question why you want to delete records if there is the possibility of undeleting them.  I would suggest that you add a "deleted" flag onto your records, and simply update the flag.  In practice, I would make this flag a date to know when the row was deleted.